# Recover hard disk data after deleting partitions

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-xp, data-recovery

When I reinstall Windows XP by mistake I deleted all five partitions. I did not format them yet though.

How can I recover the partitions? When I attach the hard disk to another PC it just says that the partition is unformated and asks "Would you like to format it?".

Comment: also http://www.easeus.com/partition-recovery/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ralford's suggestion](https://superuser.com/questions/81877/recover-hard-disk-data/81883#81883) together with [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) :

> TestDisk is a powerful free data
>   recovery software! It was primarily
>   designed to help recover lost
>   partitions and/or make non-booting
>   disks bootable again when these
>   symptoms are caused by faulty
>   software, certain types of viruses or
>   human error (such as accidentally
>   deleting a Partition Table). Partition
>   table recovery using TestDisk is
>   really easy.

Answer (score 2):

[Partition Find and Mount](http://findandmount.com/) should be able to recover your partitions.

Comment: And as a bonus, it's free!

Comment: To clarify: there are "demo" vs Pro version, but the demo has all the features and will let you recover as much data as you want.  The only limitation of the demo is the transfer rate away from the old drive.  If you have a failing drive that you've cooled down to get it working long enough for data recover, you may be limited to a few minutes and that transfer rate may be important.  But otherwise you can probably get by on the free version.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are trying to recover data**, try putting the drive into a USB converter and access it as a removeable device from your PC or Laptop's USB port.  For instance, use an IDE to USB converter, or SATA to USB converter (not sure if your drive is PATA or SATA).   I've successfully used this method to recover files on broken bootable drives on numerous occasions.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [an SATA to USB adapter](http://www.trendnet.com/products/proddetail.asp?prod=130_TU3-SA&cat=49) along with [HDD Regenerator](http://www.dposoft.net/hdd.html) with some success in the past. Good luck.

Comment: how to use it with hddregenerator ;can you post it in detail?