# How to recover the files from a deleted hard-disk partition?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recover hard disk data?](https://superuser.com/questions/81877/recover-hard-disk-data)

I have accidentally deleted one partition of a disk (deleted in **disk management**). 
I have to recover the files from that disk. 
I have already used **testdisk** software which recovers only a few files, not all!

How can I recover them?

Comment: Did you use TestDisk to recover the deleted partition?

Comment: ya i have used the TESTDISK, but it only recovers a few files not fully. so what other can i use to recover it??

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery/partition-recovery-software/free-undelete-XP-partition-software.htm) is the tool you're looking for. Quoting from the webpage:

> If the whole partition is deleted or lost, and even you could not find
>   the drive in the Windows Explorer, Partition Recovery module will
>   undelete files from lost or deleted XP partition