# If I format my drive will I lose all traces of the file completely?

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, data-recovery

I tried installing Linux to a hard drive but I chose the wrong one. I ended up deleting my media hard drive (pictures, movies, text documents, etc).

Unfortunately, I didn't make backups. Lesson learned.

I'm trying to use Recuva. However, my media drive is formatted as RAW when it was originally NTFS. Recuva doesn't recognize raw as a format.

If I format it back to NTFS, will that destroy some of the files from being recovered or will I still have a good chance of recovering everything with Recuva?

Or is there a better way I can just take files off of a raw format so I don't have to risk formatting the disk?

Comment: What lesson did you learn?

Comment: Don't format it back.  Try PhotoRec by cgsecurity, you will need to write your file to another location so have one ready.

Comment: File recovery software is file recover software.  If you have tried several different file recover suites, and they are unable to find traces of your files, then you are out of luck.

Comment: RAW is not a disk format: as used by Windows, it just means the partition has not been formatted to a filesystem type that Windows supports. It could possibly have a perfectly good ext* filesystem, created by the Linux installer. If such is the case, at least some of the old data may be overwritten and will therefore be unrecoverable. File recovery software that depends on an existant filesystem is pretty lame.

Comment: don't format it back, try not to write to it.

Answer (score 1):

That's a difficult thing to solve at a large distance. Possibly (and hopefully) the harddisk wasn't really formatted, but just the partition table changed. If your NTFS partition was set to RAW, then you can maybe set the type back to NTFS using some utility like [`gparted`](http://gparted.org). If you look at the homepage, you can find a bootable USB version (several others too).

Changing the partition should not change anything to the contents of the disk.

**Update:** If you selected  'Delete all data', then all data was really over-written and I doubt you'll find anything. This process took probably several minutes (or more). The main purpose here is to detect hard disk errors, which might escape undetected with the 'Format partition' method.

This method, 'quick format', only initializes sectors which are used for administrative (i.e. 'dir' and such) access to the disk, and leaves data alone. There's a slight chance you could recover from that, but you would loose all 'structure' - large files would be cut in small parts, and you would have to piece them together again.

In panic, a friend of mine brought me a disk with 100's of small data files (< 4kB, text), which made up his project. Luckily they were small, and I could recover them. And I could even rename them, as the name was actually inside the text file. I would not even dream about recovering an mp4.

So, I'm sorry but basically this is bad news. The one good aspect is that the slow format didn't find anything wrong with your disk, but that's not much comfort...

Comment: Im not sure what it specifically did. 
I installed kali linux and when you install to one of the partitions, one of the next choices is "format partition" or "Delete all data" 

I chose delete all data. 

Is that just the equivalent of doing a full format instead of a quick format in windows?

Comment: Terminology has changed over the years, and unluckily the vocabulary hasn't. Many years ago formatting meant really give a format to the disk, overwriting *everything* - you could even start with a completely un-magnetized disk. This isn't done anymore.  I've edited the answer above with some more info.

Answer (score 0):

**Those three steps are very important:**

**First**: Stop what you are doing! If you want to be able to recover as much as possible, definitely don't format again! Mount it as read-only, definitely don't write to it!

**Second**: Clone your original disc to a different drive or to an image file e.g. through a "sector by sector image". Then try to recover from the clone. In case there is a chance the original disc has HW failures make a second clone for save keeping, but I don't think this applies in your case.

**Third**: Only try to recover the data from the clone and **not** from the original disc since recovery actions can mess up recoverable data and make it unrecoverable in the future. So in case your recovery try (like formating the disk) messes up anything you have a chance to try again by creating a new clone from the original disc.

There are loads of existing and extensive topics on how to recover partitions and/or files with many different tools and methods. Do a search and try those suggestions first. For example [this one about recovering deleted partition tables](https://superuser.com/questions/81877/recover-hard-disk-data-after-deleting-partitions). If you run into problems you can specify your question. Most of the time - in layman's terms - reformating (at least the "quick format" - [e.g. see here for the difference in full and quick formating using Windows](https://www.partitionwizard.com/disk-recovery/quick-format-vs-full-format.html)) only overwrites certain "management"-sections of the partition, leaving most of the data intact, so you have a good chance of recovering your data.

I don't know Recuva but from your description, it seems that it can only find deleted files on an existing partition from certain partition types (RAW is not a partition type, it's just a partition Windows does not recognize/support by default). Depending on how exactly Recuva works reformating might help. But I guess - in layman's terms - it just looks for deleted files within the partition's management data (e.g. within the MFT for a Windows partition) and this data "won't be there" anymore after you formatted the drive. If it does a "full scan" (actually scanning the individual sectors in that partition)  it might work to reformat the drive again, just make sure to do a "quick format" without overwriting the actuall data.

Answer (score -1):

if you only formatted  the drive  without writing any other data, your data should be fine. I don't think that formatting it back to NTFS will destroy your data but if you can find a program that can recover the data from RAW that would be the safest way to recover them.

However, if you installed Linux after formatting the drive, you have probably  damaged some data, but might still be able to recover some info !

Answer (score -1):

If you did a full delete of your files and they really have a big value for you, I'd stop doing anything on that drive, go to a harddrive recovery lab near to yours, and... recover your data if its really valuable. I had that kind (without formatting the data or anything) of issue with a damaged hard drive and I was quite surpised of the output I got from the lab, compared to my 48h recovery software work on the disk...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score -1):

[Minitool power data recovery](http://www.powerdatarecovery.com/) is data recovery software that can recover data from lost partitions.

I would say try their free version which works for 1 GB, and if it works it is fairly inexpensive (somewhere around $70 USD) to buy the full version.