# (SOLVED) how to recover external hard disk with cmd when it's unallocated

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery

I made a new 30gb partition on my 1 tb external hard disk, used this partition to make bootable disk using win32 disk imager and selected the iso and clicked on write, it said there is a sort of error, closed that program, now all the hard disk is unallocated, as one partition when it was 4 partitions, how to use cmd codes to bring the data and recover it?? i used it once but forgot and searched google nothing is found, i need to assign my external hard disk without formatting, just to make windows discover it, please help me, it has all my projects and the company files

edit: SOLVED yay, solved by minitool partition using partition recovery, you install minitool partition wizard (i think it won't work without paid version) and then use an option called Partition recovery after you connect your external hard disk, use quick scan or deep scan if quick scan didn't work, then simply wait, when finished select all partitions you need to recover, after you continue click on apply (i think a tutorial for the software will make you understand better) and that's it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recover hard disk data after deleting partitions](https://superuser.com/questions/81877/recover-hard-disk-data-after-deleting-partitions)

Comment: Restore you data from a backup, you do have a backup don't you?

Comment: it's not duplicate testdisk didn't work and sadly i don't have a backup

Comment: Can you please include the solution onto an answer?