# Restoring Partition Table and Files After Failed DISKPART Acrobatics

Tags: data-recovery, partition-recovery, diskpart

A friend of mine wanted to convert his MBR boot drive to GPT to use UEFI.

He accessed `DISKPART` over the command prompt within the Windows installation environment using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> and used `clean` then `convert gpt` on his disk. After that he proceeded with the setup partitioning his disk and installing the system.

What methods can we try to restore the partition table and files?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/81877/recover-hard-disk-data-after-deleting-partitions & also the sidebar related questions.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin, I gave TestDisk a try on a VM, I found it would be inconvenient for him to use it. Also noting that he re-partitioned the drive after he converted it to GPT. Will that affect the outcome of TestDisk? trying to avoid the hassle of guiding through TestDisk if the outcome is expected to be not good.

Comment: Basically, the first step he took may have been a reasonably simple recovery. Adding a new OS to that result made the task much, much harder. The drive is going to have to be scraped for any scrap of info that can be found. File names & folder hierarchies are long gone, many files may be too. tbh, this is why we have backups.

Comment: Boot USB and use Recuva deep scan and save to USB for data files if any, reformat and use Win7 or 8 is my suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:** make a backup of the disc (e.g. sector by sector image), then try to recover either the backup or the original. **Don't** work on both or without the backup.

Other then that Tetsujin gave you the right hints. There are loads of existing topics on how to recover deleted partitions or repartitioned drives. Try those first. If you run into problems you can specify your question.

Comment: Thanks for you drawing my attention to take a raw image for the disk! I will go through the solutions then come back with specific question if needed. I marked your replay as the answer for your great hint and because I should in fact return with specific question.

Comment: @M.Elghamry thx and good luck!